# I'm missing data when I open a logfile on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a little stuck on this issue, I have to transform a logfile into csv, I can see the data but I think I'm missing in something.

```py
Path = "C:/Users/carlos/Documents/Scripts/logDaily/"
#filelist = os.listdir(Path)
#data = tablib.Dataset()
for i in filelist:
    if i.endswith(".log"):
        with open(Path + i, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                content = f.read()
                
                #content2 = content.split('\x7f')
                #.replace('\r', '')
                print(content)
```

With that sentences I got data but I think is missing information.

```
NormalThu Aug 13 23:13:24 202086569068565240219983872177467392  232416  230016 2834216  589472175603712217767936
NormalThu Aug 13 23:13:24 2020865180080616563204717348059653918
```

when I open the .log file on notepadd++ I got this

[image: notepad++ log opened]

I'm using python 3.4.8 with anaconda base and Visual Code. Any ideas?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I don't think anyone can reproduce what you showed, but note the time stamps are completely different between the 2 outputs

Comment: When you do `for line in f:` you read one line from the file. When you do `content = f.read()` you read the rest of the file which does not include the first line.

Comment: I mean, the results are differente because I want to show you the special characters appear on notepad++ and on the terminal of python